# alias template substitution and deduction failure with gcc

Tags: c++, templates, gcc, c++11, language-lawyer

I believe that I have found a problem with gcc's alias template handling. Essentially, gcc appears to fail to correctly substitute the alias's template-id for an alias template instantiation when referring to the types by reference.

I was able to whittle a messy real-world problem down to a minor variation on the non-normative example provided in the C++ 11 standard section temp.alias (14.5.7/2):

```
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

template <class T>
using Vec = vector<T, allocator<T>>;

template <template <class> class TT>
void f1(TT<int> v);

template <template <class> class TT>
void f2(TT<int>& v);

template <template <class, class> class TT>
void g1(TT<int, allocator<int>> v);

template <template <class, class> class TT>
void g2(TT<int, allocator<int>>& v);

void foo()
{
   Vec<int> v;

   f1(v);    // gcc and clang both correctly yield no matching function error
   g1(v);

   f2(v);    // clang yields a no matching function error
   g2(v);    // gcc yields a no matching function error
}
```

As noted above, clang 3.3 (recent pull from svn) and gcc (4.7.2, 4.8.0, and 4.8.1) agree on the handling of f1/g1 in conformance with the standard, but differ on the handling of f2/g2 (to be clear, all tested versions of gcc accept the call to f2() and error on the call to g2()). The difference between f1/g1 and f2/g2 is of course that the latter pair uses a reference parameter.

All indications, both in this example and in my real problem, are that gcc is not correctly converting the type of the instantiation of the alias template (e.g. `Vec<int>`) to the aliased type (e.g. `vector<int, allocator<int>>`) prior to trying to deduce the template parameter for the instantiations of f2 and g2.

My question is: first, is indeed gcc incorrect and clang correct here, and second, is there any straightforward way (other than not using the alias template) to convince gcc to reject f2 and match g2.

Comment: @DyP Thanks for the link, but unfortunately that's a bit different - there's no deduction going on there. In my question the issue is the timing of the point of substitution of the alias template relative to the point of deduction, so to speak. f1 is required to be rejected by the standard because v's type is really `vector<int, allocator<int>>` and cannot match a single-parameter template template parameter.

Comment: Oh, sry, I must have skipped that.. [temp.alias]/2 "Note: An alias template name is never deduced."

Comment: Your `Vec<int>` and `vector<int, allocator<int>>` mentions in the middle paragraph need to be backtick-quoted.  (HTML parsing is getting rid of stuff between angle brackets, since it's not code-quoted.)  I tried to put them in for you, but it looks like my edit was rejected.

Comment: @Adam, thanks for pointing that out, I just fixed it.

Comment: GCC 4.8.1 was released 5 hours before you posted this :) This looks like a bug in GCC, please report it to http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/ - thanks!

Comment: @Jonathon, it was in fact a day between when I checked for 4.8.1 and when I submitted a post. I'll give it a spin and then report the issue, thanks!

Comment: Hi there, I added the language lawyer tag to help attract the type of people who tend to know the answers to these questions.

Comment: +1. Looks like a bug. For what it's worth, I tested this with the latest 4.9 snapshot (20130602) of GCC, and the same problem exists there, too.

Comment: Thanks all, it was submitted to bugzilla yesterday [http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=57520](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=57520).

Answer (score 1):

Indeed this is a GCC bug. One workaround is to simply add a `typedef`.

```
   typedef Vec<int> vit;
   vit v;
```

Given that this is effective, an identity metafunction would probably also work.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the compiler has issue with the inference. Explicitly invoking the template enables a work around -- I can't speak to why gcc fails to infer as well as icpc or clang.

For icpc (ICC) 13.1.0 20130121:

```
f1<Vec> (v);    // gcc and clang both correctly yield no matching function error
g1(v);
f2<Vec>(v);    // clang yields a no matching function error
g2(v);    // gcc yields a no matching function error
```

For gcc (GCC) 4.7.2 20121109 (Red Hat 4.7.2-8):

```
f1<Vec> (v);    // gcc and clang both correctly yield no matching function error
g1(v);
f2<Vec>(v);    // clang yields a no matching function error
g2<vector>(v);    // gcc yields a no matching function error
```